# Image skewing when applying cartopy transformations

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, transformation, cartopy

I'm doing some plotting using cartopy and matplotlib, and I was recently using the PlateCarree transformation, but I changed to Mercator because Louisiana was a bit too squished for my liking. Prior to the switch, I had a logo displayed in the bottom left corner, using these two lines of code `logo = matplotlib.image.imread('/Users/ian/Desktop/M.png')
plt.imshow(logo, extent =(lon-offset -1 + .25, lon - offset + .75, lat - offset + .25, lat  - offset + 1 + .75), zorder=35)`

Where the extent of the axis was set using these points

```
ax.set_extent([lon-offset-1, lon+offset+1, lat-offset, lat+offset])
```

this is what the plot looked like using PlateCarree:
[image]

After switching to Mercator, I've gotten everything to work well except for the logo. I've added the transformation keyword argument to the image plotting line, so now it reads:

```
plt.imshow(logo, extent =(lon-offset -1 +.25, lon - offset + .75, lat - offset + .25, lat  - offset + 1 + .75), zorder=35, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

but now the the logo has lost its crispness and become skewed with the transformation, and most mysteriously, it has switched corners to the upper left corner of the plot. It now looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can change the projection of my plot without skewing this image? What I really need to do is make sure that the corner of the image is in the corner of the plot in the transformed coordinate stystem, but leave the rest of the image's placement independent of the coordinate system. I was thinking about possibly putting the image all alone in its own seperate subplot, and than trying to place that subplot directly on top of the main one. Seems like a pretty bad solution though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might get better results if you plot the image logo in axes coordinates rather than data coordinates. You can use the `ax.transAxes` transform for this, and specify the extent in axes coordinates ([0, 0] in bottom left, [1, 1] in top right).